# Cant get text of a TD by index

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have the fallowing code :

```
<table id="table1" class="class1">
    <thead>...<thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <td class>cell1</td>
            <td class>cell2</td>
            <td class>cell3</td>
            <td class>cell4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
            ....
        <\tr>
        ...
```

I need to go over all the rows and check if cell number 3 has "cell3" as text . (for starters)
then after ive found it i need to keep checking the rows for a different string in cell number 3

I've tried:

```
string="cell3"
rows=browser.table.rows
rows.each {|tr| 
    if tr.td( :index =>2).text ==string
        puts " Found #{string}" 
        string="cellK"
    end
}
```

Im doing it in a loop since there are several strings i need to find.

But im getting the fallowing error :

```
 unable to locate element, using {:index=>2, :tag_name=>"td"}
```

Any advice ? 
How can i get the text of a td?
and why cant i find td by index ?

Comment: Are you sure that each row has the same amount of tds (i.e. ```tr.td(index: 2).exists?``` always returns true. I've just tried youк code locally and it works ok. See https://gist.github.com/4369348

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that the problem is the header row in the `thead`. The table head is probably something like:

```
<thead>
    <tr id="0">
        <th class>heading1</th>
        <th class>heading2</th>
        <th class>heading3</th>
        <th class>heading4</th>
    </tr>
<thead>
```

Notice that there is a `tr`. `table.rows` will therefore include the header row. Also notice that it is using `th` instead of `td` cells. It is likely here that watir cannot find the td with index 2, because there are no tds at all in this row.

Assuming this is the problem, you have a couple solutions.

**Solution 1 - Make th and td equivalent by using cells**

Inside the loop, use `cell` instead of `td`:

```
rows.each {|tr| 
    if tr.cell( :index =>2).text == string    #Note the change here
        puts " Found #{string}" 
        string="cellK"
    end
}
```

`Table#cell` matches `td` and `th` cells. This means that `cell(:index, 2)` would match the 3rd `td` or `th` in the row. When watir checks the header row, it will now find a value.

**Solution 2 - Ignore the thead**

When getting the rows to check, confine the rows collection to only include rows in the tbody:

```
rows = browser.table.tbody.rows
```

This would then ignore the riws in the thead that are causing the problem.

Comment: That was exactly the problem , Thank you !